# jquery-calendar programmatically add / remove events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How would I add / remove an event from the [jquery-calendar](https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-calendar) plugin?

I can initialize the calendar with a bunch of events, but I'm unsure how to programmatically add/remove (programmatically) an event to the calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add:

```
var event = {....} // initialize your new calendar event
var cal = $('#your_calendar_id').data('cal');
cal.target.cal('add', event);
```

There is no way to remove (by default).  I added 2 methods for this (to jquery.calendar.js):

```
/**
         * Remove an event object to the calendar
         *
         * @param mixed uid     : The UID of the event that we want to remove.
         *
         * @scope public.
         */
        remove : function( uid ){           
            // Get shortcuts to calendar container and data.
            var $this = $(this),
            $event,
            data = $this.data(plugin_name);

            // If the calendar has been set up already...
            if( data ){

                // Find the event element.
                $event = data.cache.events[i];

                // IF we find one, we'll remove it.
                if( $event ){
                    //$($event).remove();
                    //_private.event.remove.apply( $event );
                    delete data.cache.events[uid];
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Clear all event objects from the calendar
         *
         * @scope public.
         */
        clear : function(){         
            // Get shortcuts to calendar container and data.
            var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data(plugin_name);

            // If the calendar has been set up already...
            if( data ){

                for( i in data.cache.events ){
                    //data.cache.events[i].elems.remove();
                    data.target.cal('remove', i);
                }               
            }
        },
```

To use them, you can do something like this:

```
// To remove an event
var eventId = 5 // Get your event id
var cal = $('#your_calendar_id').data('cal');
cal.target.cal('remove', eventId);

// To clear all appointments from the calendar
cal.target.cal('clear');
```